# Faceted search mysql (EAV). How to increase speed of facet counting?

Tags: mysql, faceted-search

I make faceted search using mysql and it was good on test data. Then I upload 7000 of items and 20000 of filter-item relations. Now some queries to count items amount for each filters takes much time.
Each category has own filters. Each filter has own filter values (filter_v_id).
For simplicity, I will show two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_cat` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publicate` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `item_cat`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`category_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`);


CREATE TABLE `filter_item` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_v_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter_v` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `filter_item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`filter_id`,`filter_v_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id_2` (`item_id`,`filter_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id_3` (`item_id`,`filter_id`,`filter_v_id`),
  ADD KEY `filter_id` (`filter_id`,`filter_v_id`),
  ADD KEY `filter_id_2` (`filter_id`);
```

[DB Fiddle - fast query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6NMdtgxaYRfFwpocC3JPuC/1)
Category_id=70 has 46 items, and any set of filters fast (100-150ms)

```
SELECT `filter_id`,`filter_v_id`, count(`item_id`) as `cnt` FROM        
(SELECT * FROM `item_cat` WHERE `category_id`='70') as `ic`         
JOIN `filter_item` as `fi` USING(`item_id`) 
WHERE `item_id` IN(         
SELECT `ic`.`item_id` FROM          
    (SELECT * FROM `item_cat` WHERE `category_id`='70') as `ic`             
    JOIN `filter_item` as `fi` USING(`item_id`)                     
    GROUP BY `ic`.`item_id`         
    HAVING (                
        (`fi`.`filter_id` = '1' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '932')=1  OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '938')=1  OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '1006')=1 ) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '17' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '563')=1 ) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '28' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v` >= '2' AND `fi`.`filter_v` <= '22500')=1) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '46' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '580')=1  OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '595')=1  OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '559')=1 ) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '70' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '564')=1 ) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '73' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '562')=1 ) 
        AND (`fi`.`filter_id` = '74' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '561')=1 )            
    )
)   
GROUP BY `filter_id`,`filter_v_id`
```

[DB Fiddle - slow query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kw5TLyLiyJ8aMqkFiXTLcy/2)
Category_id=52 has 651 items, and one applied filter took 3000ms+

```
SELECT  `filter_id`,`filter_v_id`, count(`item_id`) as `cnt` FROM   
(SELECT * FROM `item_cat` WHERE `category_id`='52') as `ic`
JOIN `filter_item` as `fi` USING(`item_id`) 
WHERE `item_id` IN(         
    SELECT `item_id` FROM           
    (SELECT * FROM `item_cat` WHERE `category_id`='52') as `ic`
    JOIN `filter_item` as `fi` USING(`item_id`)
    GROUP BY `ic`.`item_id`         
    HAVING (                
        (`fi`.`filter_id` = '47' OR  MAX(`fi`.`filter_v_id` = '474')=1 )            
    )               
)
GROUP BY `filter_id`,`filter_v_id`
```

Please tell me how to increase the speed of query?

Comment: Avoid `IN( SELECT ...`).  Don't use a derived table when a `JOIN` works just as well.

Comment: Yes, but I can't build query using  `JOIN` - error. `HAVING` makes some magic (for me) here, found facet count for each facet and it not work with `JOIN`. I even can't use subquery from `IN` without parent query.